# How would contravariance be used in Java generics?

Tags: java, generics, contravariance

In Java, covariance allows the API designer to specify that an instance may be generalised as a certain type or any of that type's subtypes. For example:

```
List<? extends Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Circle>(); 
// where type Circle extends Shape
```

Contravariance goes the other way. It allows us to specify that an instance may be generalised  as a certain type or supertype.

```
List<? super Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Geometry>();
// where Shape extends Geometry
```

How is Java generic's contravariance useful? When would you choose to use it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, your second example would allow you to write:

```
Shape shape = getShapeFromSomewhere();
shapes.add(shape);
```

whereas you couldn't do that with the first form. It's not useful as often as covariance, I'll grant you.

One area where it *can* be useful is in terms of comparisons. For example, consider:

```
class AreaComparer implements Comparator<Shape>
...
```

You can use that to compare *any* two shapes... so it would be nice if we could *also* use it to sort a `List<Circle>` for example. Fortunately, we can do that with contravariance, which is why there's an overload for `Collections.sort` of:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Comment: Does this mean I could call Collections.sort(shapes, new Comparator<Object>() { ... }); ? Object is <? super Shape>, right?

Comment: @Synesso: Yup, if you've got a comparator which can compare any two Objects, that can compare any two Shapes, so it's safe.

Comment: **@JonSkeet:** still, I do not get why we need explicitly `super` in the second case. I understand that using `extends` will not help to add any Shape to the List, but `List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Geometry>();?` would have equally worked as well, right? I do not find the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html) from Oracle useful either to fully grasp the usefulness of `super` in this case :-(

Comment: @zencv: No, because an `ArrayList<Geometry>` *isn't* a `List<Shape>`. A `List<Shape>` has a `get` method such that the return value will always be a `Shape` reference or `null` - whereas an `ArrayList<Geometry>` can contain elements which aren't shapes.

Comment: @JonSkeet: sorry, I meant to write `List<Geometry> shapes = new ArrayList<Geometry>();` instead of `List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Geometry>();`. I get why the latter won't work, but I am still not fully sure why writing `? super Shape` is of any benefit when you can just write `Geometry`; especially given that Java doesn't support multiple inheritance. Only scenario I can imagine is when `Shape` implements more than one interface, then we can write either `List<? super Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Geometry>();` or `List<? super Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<AnotherSuper>();` . Thanks!!

Comment: @zencv: The point is that if you want to write a method which will add a bunch of `Shape` elements to an existing list, you don't mind whether that's a `List<Shape>` or a `List<Geometry>` - so you could have a method parameter of `List<? super Shape> listToAddTo` for example.

Comment: @Joschua: That's not what that means - it means "It's a list of some type, and that type extends Shape". So it could be (say) a `List<Square>`, and you shouldn't be able to add a `Circle` to that. A "list that contains elements which are Shape or extend from it" is just a `List<Shape>`.

Answer (score 36):

Here's a relevant excerpt from [Java Generics and Collections](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527754):

### 2.4. The Get and Put Principle

It may be good practice to insert wildcards whenever possible, but how do you decide
which wildcard to use? Where should you use `extends`, where should you use `super`,
and where is it inappropriate to use a wildcard at all?

Fortunately, a simple principle determines which is appropriate.

> **The Get and Put Principle**: use an
>   `extends` wildcard when you only get
>   values out of a structure, use a `super`
>   wildcard when you only put values into
>   a structure, and don't use a wildcard
>   when you both get and put.

We already saw this principle at work in the signature of the copy method:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

The method gets values out of the source src, so it is declared with an `extends` wildcard,
and it puts values into the destination dst, so it is declared with a `super` wildcard.
Whenever you use an iterator, you get values out of a structure, so use an `extends`
wildcard. Here is a method that takes a collection of numbers, converts each to a double,
and sums them up:

```
public static double sum(Collection<? extends Number> nums) {
    double s = 0.0;
    for (Number num : nums) s += num.doubleValue();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This is also known by the mnemonic "PECS": Producer Extends, Consumer Super.  (Many explanations on the web.)

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg true, but I didn't know that in 2010 :-)

Answer (score 8):

For example, when implementing the [Collections.addAll()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) method, you need a collection that can contain some type T or a supertype of T. The method then looks like:

```
public static <T> void addAll(Collection<? super T> collection, T... objects) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Demonstration code (useless IRL):
`List<Animal> l = List.of();`

`Collections.addAll(l, new Cow(), new Cow());`

Thanks to the contravariance we can add cows in a list of animals.