# Generics cast issue

Tags: java, generics

Here's my issue: given these classes

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

This code compiles:

```
    List<Class<? extends A>> list = Arrays.asList(B.class, A.class);
```

And this does not:

```
    List<Class<? extends A>> anotherList = Arrays.asList(B.class);
```

What gives?

---

**UPDATE:** This code compiles in Java 8. Apparently, due to 'Improved Type Inference'.

Comment: the first line is not compiling for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the first example, the inferred type of the `Arrays.asList()` call is `List<Class<? extends A>>`, which is obviously assignable to a variable of the same type.

In the second example, the type of the right side is `List<Class<B>>`. While `Class<B>` **is** assignable to `Class<? extends A>`, `List<Class<B>>` **is not** assignable to `List<Class<? extends A>>`. It would be assignable to `List<? extends Class<? extends A>>`.

The reason for this is the same one as why a `List<B>` isn't assignable to `List<A>`. If it was, it would make the following (not-typesafe) code possible:

```
List<Class<B>> bb = new ArrayList<B>();
List<Class<? extends A>> aa = bb;
aa.add(A.class);
```

Comment: Understood. Could you point me to JLS/Sun tutorial where can I read how inference work?

Comment: Java Generics tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html

Comment: @Victor The relevant bit of the JLS seems to be this: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#341287

Comment: The tutorials mostly mention that type inference does occur without going into detail. My intuitive understanding is that type inference tries to find the most specific type parameters that will match the compile-time types of all the method.

Answer (score 5):

This will compile:

```
List<Class<? extends A>> numbers = Arrays.<Class<? extends A>>asList(B.class);
```

Comment: +1 this is the correct solution. explicitly specifying the parameter because it differs from what is inferred

Answer (score 2):

```
Arrays.asList(B.class);
```

is generified as

```
List<Class<B>> numbers = Arrays.asList(B.class);
```

Since it has only 1 attribute of type `T` that match the parameterized type (in this case, `B.class`).

Comment: Can you please give pointer to JLS or Sun tutorial where I can read about it?

Answer (score 1):

Damn good question, and I don't know the answer, but here's a work around:

```
List<Class<? extends A>> numbers = new ArrayList<Class<? extends A>>(Arrays.asList(B.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, we can rewrite the code as below

```
List<Class<? extends A>> asListA = Arrays.asList(B.class, A.class);
List<Class<B>> asListB = Arrays.asList(B.class);

List<Class<? extends A>> numbers = asListA;
List<Class<? extends A>> numbers2 = asListB; // it will fail here
```

And @Inerdia explained the details already.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of Covariance/Contravariance in Generics. The following SO question should help you understand and solve the problem:

[Demonstrate covariance and contravariance in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java)

[How would contravariance be used in Java generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861132/how-would-contravariance-be-used-in-java-generics)