# List<Map<String, String>> vs List<? extends Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

Is there any difference between

```
List<Map<String, String>>
```

and

```
List<? extends Map<String, String>>
```

?

If there is no difference, what is the benefit of using `? extends`?

Comment: I love java but this is one of the things that is not that good...

Comment: I feel that if we read it like "anything that extends ...", it becomes clear.

Comment: Incredible, over 12K views in about 3 days?!!

Comment: It reached the Hacker News front page. Congrats.

Comment: @r3st0r3 Could you please give me the link of that page? :)

Comment: @Eng.Found here it is. No longer on the front page, but was there yesterday. http://news.ycombinator.net/item?id=3751901 (yesterday being mid-Sunday here in India.)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

The difference is that, for example, a

```
List<HashMap<String,String>>
```

is a

```
List<? extends Map<String,String>>
```

but not a

```
List<Map<String,String>>
```

So:

```
void withWilds( List<? extends Map<String,String>> foo ){}
void noWilds( List<Map<String,String>> foo ){}

void main( String[] args ){
    List<HashMap<String,String>> myMap;

    withWilds( myMap ); // Works
    noWilds( myMap ); // Compiler error
}
```

You would think a `List` of `HashMap`s should be a `List` of `Map`s, but there's a good reason why it isn't:

Suppose you could do:

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> hashMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

List<Map<String,String>> maps = hashMaps; // Won't compile,
                                          // but imagine that it could

Map<String,String> aMap = Collections.singletonMap("foo","bar"); // Not a HashMap

maps.add( aMap ); // Perfectly legal (adding a Map to a List of Maps)

// But maps and hashMaps are the same object, so this should be the same as

hashMaps.add( aMap ); // Should be illegal (aMap is not a HashMap)
```

So this is why a `List` of `HashMap`s shouldn't be a `List` of `Map`s.

Comment: Still, `HashMap` is a `Map` due to the polymorphism.

Comment: Right, but a `List` of `HashMap`s isn't a `List` of `Map`s.

Comment: This is called [Bounded quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification)

Comment: Good example. Also worth noting is that even if you declare `List<Map<String,String>> maps = hashMaps; ` and `HashMap<String,String> aMap = new HashMap<String, String>();`, you will still find that `maps.add(aMap);` is illegal while `hashMaps.add(aMap);` is legal. The purpose is to prevent addition of wrong types, but it won't allow addition of right types (compiler can't determine the "right" type during compile time)

Comment: @Raze no, actually you *can* add a `HashMap` to a list of `Map`s, both of your examples are legal, if I'm reading them correctly.

Comment: @trutheality, oops! I meant to say `List<? extends Map<String, String>> maps = ...`!!!

Comment: @Raze Ah, yes. The general rule I like to remember is that you don't add to `<? extends ...>` collections and don't read from `<? super ...>` collections.

Comment: @trutheality 28 up-votes left to get the great answer badge ;)

Comment: @trutheality congrats on getting the gold great answer badge :)

Answer (score 24):

You cannot assign expressions with types such as `List<NavigableMap<String,String>>` to the first.

(If you want to know why you can't assign `List<String>` to `List<Object>` see a **zillion** other questions on SO.)

Comment: can explain further it ? i cant understand or any link for good practice?

Comment: @Samir Explain what? `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`? - see, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246137/java-generics-cannot-cast-listsubclass-to-listsuperclass

Comment: This doesn't explain what the difference is between with or without `? extends`. Nor does it explain the correlation with super/subtypes or co/contravariance (if there is any).

Answer (score 18):

What I'm missing in the other answers is a reference to how this relates to co- and contravariance and sub- and supertypes (that is, polymorphism) in general and to Java in particular. This may be well understood by the OP, but just in case, here it goes:

### Covariance

If you have a class `Automobile`, then `Car` and `Truck` are their subtypes. Any Car can be assigned to a variable of type Automobile, this is well-known in OO and is called polymorphism. Covariance refers to using this same principle in scenarios with generics or delegates. Java doesn't have delegates (yet), so the term applies only to generics.

I tend to think of covariance as standard polymorphism what you would expect to work without thinking, because:

```
List<Car> cars;
List<Automobile> automobiles = cars;
// You'd expect this to work because Car is-a Automobile, but
// throws inconvertible types compile error.
```

The reason of the error is, however, correct: `List<Car>` *does not* inherit from `List<Automobile>` and thus cannot be assigned to each other. Only the generic type parameters have an inherit relationship. One might think that the Java compiler simply isn't smart enough to properly understand your scenario there. However, you can help the compiler by giving him a hint:

```
List<Car> cars;
List<? extends Automobile> automobiles = cars;   // no error
```

### Contravariance

The reverse of co-variance is contravariance. Where in covariance the parameter types must have a subtype relationship, in contravariance they must have a supertype relationship. This can be considered as an inheritance upper-bound: any supertype is allowed up and including the specified type:

```
class AutoColorComparer implements Comparator<Automobile>
    public int compare(Automobile a, Automobile b) {
        // Return comparison of colors
    }
```

This can be used with [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)

// Which you can call like this, without errors:
List<Car> cars = getListFromSomewhere();
Collections.sort(cars, new AutoColorComparer());
```

You could even call it with a comparer that compares objects and use it with any type.

### When to use contra or co-variance?

A bit OT perhaps, you didn't ask, but it helps understanding answering your question. In general, when you *get* something, use covariance and when you *put* something, use contravariance. This is best explained in [an answer to Stack Overflow question *How would contravariance be used in Java generics?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3863471/111575).

### So what is it then with `List<? extends Map<String, String>>`

You use `extends`, so the rules for *covariance* applies. Here you have a list of maps and each item you store in the list must be a `Map<string, string>` or derive from it. The statement `List<Map<String, String>>` cannot derive from `Map`, but must be *a* `Map`.

Hence, the following will work, because `TreeMap` inherits from `Map`:

```
List<Map<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
mapList.add(new TreeMap<String, String>());
```

but this will not:

```
List<? extends Map<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<? extends Map<String, String>>();
mapList.add(new TreeMap<String, String>());
```

and this will not work either, because it does not satisfy the covariance constraint:

```
List<? extends Map<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<? extends Map<String, String>>();
mapList.add(new ArrayList<String>());   // This is NOT allowed, List does not implement Map
```

### What else?

This is probably obvious, but you may have already noted that using the `extends` keyword only applies to that parameter and not to the rest. I.e., the following will not compile:

```
List<? extends Map<String, String>> mapList = new List<? extends Map<String, String>>();
mapList.add(new TreeMap<String, Element>())  // This is NOT allowed
```

Suppose you want to allow any type in the map, with a key as string, you can use `extend` on each type parameter. I.e., suppose you process XML and you want to store AttrNode, Element etc in a map, you can do something like:

```
List<? extends Map<String, ? extends Node>> listOfMapsOfNodes = new...;

// Now you can do:
listOfMapsOfNodes.add(new TreeMap<Sting, Element>());
listOfMapsOfNodes.add(new TreeMap<Sting, CDATASection>());
```

Comment: Nothing in "So what is it then with..." will compile.

Comment: @NobleUplift: it's hard to help you out if you don't supply the error message you get. Consider also, as an alternative, to ask a new question on SO to get your answer, larger chance of success. The code above are just snippets, it depends you implemented it in your scenario.

Comment: I don't have a new question, I have improvements. `List<? extends Map<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<? extends Map<String, String>>(); mapList.add(new TreeMap<String, String>());` results in `found: ? extends java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> required: class or interface without bounds`. `List<Map<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(); mapList.add(new TreeMap<String, String>());` works perfectly. The last example is obviously correct.

Comment: @NobleUplift: sorry, travelling long time, will fix when I'm back, and thanks for pointing out the glaring error! :)

Comment: No problem, I'm just glad it will be fixed. I made the edits for you if you want to approve them.

Answer (score 4):

Today, I have used this feature, so here's my very fresh real-life example. (I have changed class and method names to generic ones so they won't distract from the actual point.)

I have a method that's meant to accept a `Set` of `A` objects that I originally wrote with this signature:

```
void myMethod(Set<A> set)
```

But it want to actually call it with `Set`s of subclasses of `A`. But this is not allowed! (The reason for that is, `myMethod` could add objects to `set` that are of type `A`, but not of the subtype that `set`'s objects are declared to be at the caller's site. So this could break the type system if it were possible.)

Now here come generics to the rescue, because it works as intended if I use this method signature instead:

```
<T extends A> void myMethod(Set<T> set)
```

or shorter, if you don't need to use the actual type in the method body:

```
void myMethod(Set<? extends A> set)
```

This way, `set`'s type becomes a collection of objects of the actual subtype of `A`, so it becomes possible to use this with subclasses without endangering the type system.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, there could be two below versions of defining a List:

1. `List<? extends Map<String, String>>`
2. `List<?>`

2 is very open. It can hold any object type. This may not be useful in case you want to have a map of a given type. In case someone accidentally puts a different type of map, for example, `Map<String, int>`. Your consumer method might break.

In order to ensure that `List` can hold objects of a given type, Java generics introduced `? extends`. So in #1, the `List` can hold any object which is derived from `Map<String, String>` type. Adding any other type of data would throw an exception.