# Create list with different objects

Tags: java, list

I have a method that takes in a `List<>` and adds all the numbers in the list together and returns if the number is = 100

My problem is that I want to use the same method for a number of different types of lists

So instead of having this

```
public boolean checkPercent(List<BarStaff> associates){..same..}
public boolean checkPercent(List<Waiters> associates){..same..}
public boolean checkPercent(List<KitchenStaff> associates){..same..}
```

I want to have this

```
public boolean checkPercent(List<could be any type> associates){..same..}
```

Instead of reusing the same code just of different lists, is there a way to use the same code for all the different types of lists (the staff have the same values in them so they are not different in any way)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a [parameterized method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html):

```
public <T> boolean checkPercent(List<T> associates)
{
    // snip...
}
```

or just [accept any list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

```
public boolean checkPercent(List<?> associates)
{
    // snip...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You may create a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html):

```
public <T> boolean checkPercent(List<T> associates) {
    ... your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use generics:

```
public <T> boolean checkPercent(List<T> associates){...}
```

Answer (score 2):

The object-oriented approach would be to have `BarStaff`, `Waiters`, and `KitchenStaff` implement a `Employee` interface that has a method `public int getPercentage()`.

```
public boolean checkPercent(List<? extends Employee> associates)
{
    foreach (Employee associate in associates)
    {
        int i = associate.getPercentage();
        // rest of code.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810445/listmapstring-string-vs-list-extends-mapstring-string

Comment: Extends and implements are different.

Comment: This could work if it was an array, i.e `Employee[]` will accept `BarStaff[]`. However, I think the right way to do is `List<? extends Employee>`.