# Container of Enums in java

Tags: java, enums

In Java I can do this:

```
    enum Color {RED, BLUE, GREEN };
    enum Weight {LIGHT, HEAVY }

    Enum e = Color.RED;
    assertEquals(Color.RED, e);
    e = Weight.HEAVY;
    assertEquals(Weight.HEAVY, e);
```

I can put the enum in a Map and that still works:

```
    Map<String, Enum> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("color", Color.RED);
    map.put("weight", Weight.HEAVY);
    assertEquals(Color.RED, map.get("color"));
    assertEquals(Weight.HEAVY, map.get("weight"));
```

However, I am not able to do the same with collections of enums.

```
   List<Enum> enumList = new ArrayList<Color>();  //error
```

Is that not allowed in Java or am I just doing it wrong?

Is there a better way to maintain a mapping of properties to Enums that represent them?

Comment: You are doing different things in your `Map` example vs your `List` example. Do you see that? (The type arguments, inferred and provided.)

Comment: Also, don't use raw types.

Comment: The "List<Enum> is not a subtype of List<Color>" seems to be what I was missing here. So how can I generically store different collections of Enums then?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810445/listmapstring-string-vs-list-extends-mapstring-string

Comment: Why do you want to have a list of enums without knowing what kind of enums they are e.g., whether they are colors, weights, or something else? What possible use could this serve?

Comment: I am writing a library that will work with user Enums and pass them around and call Callable's on them etc so I don't really care what the enum type is - the user will give me a Callable that will evaluate it, but I do need to be able to take any type of enum generically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<? extends Enum> enumList = new ArrayList<Color>();
```

`Color` is **subtype** of an `Enum` but  `List<Color>` is **not subtype** of `List<Enum>`.

You have to explicitly say "List of something that is subetype of `Enum`" which in Java is:

`List<? extends Enum>`

Answer (score 2):

The type argument to your list appears to be incorrect,

```
List<Enum> enumList = new ArrayList<Color>();
```

Should probably be

```
List<Enum> enumList = new ArrayList<Enum>();
```

or (use the [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4166966/2970947) - Java 7 and up with)

```
List<Enum> enumList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` will always function as a `List`.
`Color` will always function as an `Enum`.

However:
`ArrayList<Color>` will **not** always function as a `List<Enum>`.

Example:

```
    List<Enum> EvilList = new ArrayList<Color>();
    EvilList.add(Some other Enum);
    // Because EvilList is, in its definition, a List<Enum>, allowing your code to
    // compile would break the type safety that generics are meant to preserve.
```

Note, however, that `List<Color>` would not break generic type safety.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use wildcards for that kind of assignment:

```
List<? extends Enum> enumList = new ArrayList<Color>();
```

Wildcards allow that kind of assignment, though you cant do certain things on the collection.. such as adding elements that extends Enum (since you wouldnt know the type referenced object). You can only get elements from Enum and up.

If you want to be able to keep adding elements, make the array list like this:

```
ArrayList<Enum>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Enum` is a generic class so give it it's generic parameter:

```
List<Enum<Colour>> l = new ArrayList<Enum<Colour>>();
```

which can be shortened to:

```
List<Colour> l = new ArrayList<Colour>();
```

the following is valid code:

```
    List<Enum<Colour>> ecl = new ArrayList<Enum<Colour>>();
    List<Colour> cl = new ArrayList<Colour>();
    ecl.add(Colour.Blue);
    cl.add(Colour.Blue);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only **1 value per enum** to store:

```
Map<Class<? extends Enum>, Enum<?>> map = new HashMap<Class<? extends Enum>, Enum<?>>();
map.put(Color.class, Color.BLUE);
map.put(Weight.class, Weight.LIGHT);
Color color = getFromMap(map, Color.class);

private static <T> T getFromMap(Map<Class<? extends Enum>, Enum<?>> map, Class<T> itemClass) {
    return (T) map.get(itemClass);
}
```

otherwise

```
List<Enum<?>> list = new ArrayList<Enum<?>>();
list.add(Color.BLUE);
list.add(Weight.LIGHT);
Color fromList = getFromList(list, 1, Color.class);

private static <T> T getFromList(List<Enum<?>> list, int i, Class<Color> outType) {
    return (T) list.get(i);
}
```