# Prevent Kotlin from forcing Java to see a wildcard type

Tags: kotlin

This works fine:

```
class Wrapped<out T>(val value: T)

open class Wrapper<T> {
    fun wrap(map: T): Wrapped<T> = Wrapped(map)
}

class Wrapper2 : Wrapper<Map<String, String>>()

val wrapped: Wrapped<Map<String, String>> = Wrapper2().wrap(mapOf())
```

But, when I try to access `Wrapper2.wrap` from Java, the Map comes back with a wildcard type:

```java
    Map<String, String> toWrap = new HashMap<>();
    Wrapped<Map<String, String>> result;
    result = new Wrapper<Map<String, String>>().wrap(toWrap); // ok
    result = new Wrapper2().wrap(toWrap); // NOT ok, returns Wrapped<Map<String, ? extends String>>
```

I can work around this by overriding `wrap` in `Wrapper2` with the explicit type.

Why does `Wrapper2.wrap` return a different type than `Wrapper.wrap`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can suppress Kotlin using wildcards in generics as [described in the Kotlin reference](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics) where it describes the `@JvmSuppressWildcards` annotation (or the reverse of that `@JvmWildcard` annotation).

From the docs:

> On the other hand, if we don't need wildcards where they are generated, we can use `@JvmSuppressWildcards`:
>
> ```
> fun unboxBase(box: Box<@JvmSuppressWildcards Base>): Base = box.value
> // is translated to 
> // Base unboxBase(Box<Base> box) { ... }
> ```
>
> NOTE: `@JvmSuppressWildcards` can be used not only on individual type arguments, but on entire declarations, such as functions or classes, causing all wildcards inside them to be suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
class Wrapper2 : Wrapper<Map<String, String>>()
```

to

```
class Wrapper2 : Wrapper<MutableMap<String, String>>()
```

You'll see in the Kotlin source,

```
public interface Map<K, out V> {
```

whereas:

```
public interface MutableMap<K, V> : Map<K, V> {
```

I believe `out V` is the reason you're getting `? extends String`, see [Covariance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) under the generics docs for Kotlin and a quick search on Google should give you some more insight into [covariance and contravariance in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810445/listmapstring-string-vs-list-extends-mapstring-string#9810499) .

Comment: Yes, this is exactly why Kotlin's (immutable) `Map<>` behaves the way it does, thank you!