# Dagger 2 doesn't recognize provide method in Kotlin. Java works fine

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Dagger doesn't recognize one provided method in Kotlin. This is the important part of the module:

```
    @Provides
    @AppScope
    fun provideClient(cache: Cache, interceptors: List<Interceptor>?): OkHttpClient {

        val httpBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()

        interceptors?.let {
            for (interceptor in interceptors) {
                httpBuilder.addInterceptor(interceptor)
            }
        }

        return httpBuilder
                .cache(cache)
                .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @AppScope
    fun provideInterceptors(): List<Interceptor>? {
        return listOf(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(WebServiceConfig.LOGGING_LEVEL))
    }
```

The error message is as follows:

```
AppComponent.java:15: error: java.util.List<? extends okhttp3.Interceptor> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

If I use MutableList, then it works. Therefore the question is: what is the problem with List in Dagger2 / Kotlin?

Comment: can you put your interceptor provider over your client provider and try to re-build again?

Comment: That makes no different. But I tried it. Same problem.

Comment: i know it should not make a difference but i fixed a problem somehow like this. when you're trying to use dagger with kotlin you face some interesting problems and solutions.

Comment: You could try and have a look at the Kotlin Bytecode (Action "Show Kotlin Bytecode) and decompile it to java, to see if they mix up some types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out this is a generics interop issue.

When you use a `List` of an interface (like `Interceptor`) as a parameter in Kotlin, you see it as having a wildcard for the type parameter of the list from Java's point of view, because `List` is covariant:

```
OkHttpClient provideClient(List<? extends Interceptor> interceptors) { ... }
```

However, this wildcard doesn't get added for return types.

```
List<Interceptor> provideInterceptors() { ... }
```

You can check this by creating an instance of your module in a Java file, and looking at the methods offered by the autocompletion.

So the problem is that Dagger is looking for a `List<? extends Interceptor>` while your other method is returning a `List<Interceptor>`.

Possible solutions:

1. Use the [`@JvmSuppressWildCards`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-suppress-wildcards/index.html) annotation to prevent the wildcard from being added (see a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209856/prevent-kotlin-from-forcing-java-to-see-a-wildcard-type)). This can be used in just about any scope, all the way from the entire module to only on the single type parameter you're having an issue with:

   ```
   interceptors: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards Interceptor>?
   ```
2. Add explicit `out` variance on the `List` that you're returning in the `provideInterceptors` method. Interestingly, this doesn't show when you look at autocompletion from Java, but it fixes the build.

   ```
   fun provideInterceptors(): List<out Interceptor>? { ... }
   ```
3. Use the `MutableList` interface, which as you've discovered, doesn't have this issue.

---

As for why this only happens when you use a `List` and not a `MutableList`: `List` only has its type parameter in `out` positions, and therefore, it's covariant. This causes the the wildcard to be generated for a `List` but not for the invariant `MutableList` (which is why that works fine).

Also note that this wildcard generation only happens when the type parameter is a non-final type (an open class or an interface). So you wouldn't get this issue for, say a `List<StringBuilder>` (which is final), but you'd get it for a 
`List<BufferedReader>` (which isn't).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I used number 3: MutableList works.