# Java: is a Lists's generic type parameter covariant or contravariant when consuming?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, covariance, contravariance

I'm a little bit confused about covariance and contravariance. Do we say that in Java something is generally contravariant when we use `? super X`.

Now reading my book I understood the following concept:

this is contravariant:

```
method(Predicate<? super X> pred)
```

but this one it's covariant:

```
method(List<? super X> list)  //And then we use add for a list of course
```

This concept is not written explicitly exactly how I'm asking to you so I want to know, is this definition correct? If yes, why the first one is contravariant and the last one covariant if both are using `super` keyword?

Comment: It would be good if you could link or mention where did you get those definitions.

Comment: Related: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: Generally [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19739576/5515060) lays out the rules. The linked answer illustrates it very good with the image

Comment: "Now assuming that this is correct" is a good place to stop, because it's clearly contradictory.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't think so. I'm asking if this definition is correct or not and you can just answer if yes/not followed by a valid motivation that confirms your theory.

Comment: @Bondavalli69 ok, then I'll rephrase: it's worth questioning the apparent contradiction.

Comment: @AndyTurner Changed my question as well. Now should be more detailed and clear. There is no reference about what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

We don’t often talk about variance in Java, people generally just apply [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Both your examples are identical in terms of variance, as it does not matter what are the actual method definitions inside `Predicate` or `List` to evaluate their variance.

So what is it here?

Well let’s say we have `Cat extends Animal` and `method(List<? super Cat> list)` (or the same with `Predicate`). This method would accept `List<? super Cat>`, `List<Cat>`, `List<Animal>` or even `List<? super Animal` or `List<Object>` as argument, i.e. `List` whose generic type is a supertype of `Cat`.

Using [the `≤` notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8482091/525036)), we see that `? super` inverses the relationship: `Cat ≤ Animal` implies `List<Animal> ≤ List<? super Cat>`, so this is contravariance as the types get swapped.

Conversely, `List<Cat> ≤ List<? extends Animal>`, i.e. you can assign a value of type `List<Cat>` to a variable/parameter of type `List<? extends Animal>`. As it does not swap the types (`Cat ≤ Animal`), this is covariance. (see also [How would contravariance be used in Java generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3861132/525036))

Citing the same Wikipedia article’s [section on use-site variance annotations (wildcards)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Use-site_variance_annotations_(wildcards)) (as in Java):

> wildcard types are *covariant in their upper bounds* (and also *contravariant in their lower bounds*). In total, given a wildcard type like `C<? extends T>`, there are three ways to form a subtype: by specializing the class `C`, by specifying a tighter bound `T`, or by replacing the wildcard `?` with a specific type.

(you can replace `C<? extends T>` with `C<? super T>` in the above, it just makes `T` a lower bound instead of an upper bound).