# In Java why aren't functions by default covariant with the return types and contravariant with the parameter type

Tags: java, inheritance, covariance, contravariance, type-parameter

Take a look at the following code

If Functions were contravariant with the parameter type, this would work, since they are not, the compiler complains:

```
  // contravariant with the parameter type
  final Function<Object, Number> objToNUmberfoo = (v) -> 2;
  giveMeAFunction(objToNUmberfoo); // THIS GIVES A COMPILER ERROR

  public void giveMeAFunction(Function<Integer, Number> foo) 
  {
         // do something
  }
```

Same goes here for covariance:

```
   // covariant with the return type
   final Function<Integer, BigDecimal> intToBigDecimal = (v) -> 2;
   giveMeAFunction2(intToBigDecimal); // THIS GIVES A COMPILER ERROR


   public void giveMeAFunction2(Function<Integer, Number> foo)
   {
          // do something
   }
```

To fix the compiler errors we should declare the methods respectively:

```
public void giveMeAFunction2(Function<? super Integer, Number> foo)
{
       // do something
}
```

and

```
public void giveMeAFunction2(Function<Integer, ? extends Number> foo)
{
       // do something
}
```

What I really don't get here is why isn't the java compiler allowing it by default ?
I cannot think of any situation where this wouldn’t be safe at runtime...maybe I am wrong here ?

And more importantly what would be the consequences of that ?

Why we need to explicitly opt in for that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would contravariance be used in Java generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861132/how-would-contravariance-be-used-in-java-generics)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `Function<T,R>` interface itself but with generics in Java in general. With Java generics if you want covariance / contravariance you **must** explicitly state it. The `Function<T,R>` interface uses generics and therefore has to follow the rules all generic classes and interface must follow.